# Where does gcc keep its built-in include directory paths

Tags: linux, gcc

GCC has built in include directories for certain standard headers.  I just need to know where this list is.  My newly compiled gcc will not compile my little test C++ program because it cannot find standard headers.  I think it fails because of some config options I used to make my file system more organized.  I set the bindir and libdir, which I think might have screwed up the built-in include paths for some reason.

Program (dummy.c):

```
#include <iostream>
void main(){}
```

Command:

```
g++ dummy.c
```

Error:

```
dummy.c:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor can tell you what it uses

```
cpp -x c++ -v

...

    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/include/c++/4.4
     /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu
     /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include-fixed
     /usr/include/i486-linux-gnu
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
```

You can add directories to the search path by setting the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and/or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variiables

Comment: ah great, I was looking for some way to actually print those out.  Now I know for certain that they are screwed up.

Comment: It appears that later versions of gcc don't have a default specs file to read from, but can generate one for later customisation. There is more discussion about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

Comment: I made some customizations to my specs file to add the real include directories and I can now compile.  Usually I would not let such a hack fly but this is a temp toolchain anyway, thanks!